# JavaScript undo-buffer cleared after manipulativ textarea

Tags: javascript, html

In my Web App I have have an TextEditor, which can be manipulated by some buttons.
For example:

```
<textarea id="textareaId"></textarea>
<button onclick="add()">Click me</button>
<script>
  add() {
    document.getElementById('textareaId').value += 'some content';
  }
</script>
```

The issue is, that the user cant undo this (for example by shortcut ctrl + z).
It looks like that the the undo-buffor for the textarea gets cleared by that. Is there any way to do the changes without losing the option of undoing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache the `textarea`'s value using an array as stack:

```js
var valuesStack = [];
var textarea = document.getElementById('textareaId');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') restore();
});

function cache() {
  valuesStack.push(textarea.value);
}

function add() {
  cache();
  textarea.value += 'some content';
}

function restore() {
  var value = valuesStack.pop();
  if (value === undefined) textarea.value = "";
  else textarea.value = value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaId" onchange="cache()"></textarea>
<button onclick="add()">Click me</button>
```